# Compare user input to two columns and return value from 3rd predefined column

Tags: excel, datatable, vlookup

So I am trying to understand how to use excel to complete this exercise.

Basically, I have 4 columns (A, B, C, D). Looks like this:

```
    A     B      C    D    E

    CRT   Carrot CRT  CR
    Apple Apple  APL  AP
```

Basically, I need to scan down column A and compare it to columns B & C. If the word in A matched either the full word in B or the three letter word in C, then I need to take the two-letter word in D and write it in column E.

I've managed to Use VLOOKUP to scan column A and column C and then append to E, however, I can't figure out how to have excel scan both B & C and then append D to E. (main issue here is that the input in A sometimes matches B and sometimes matched C).

Thanks!

Comment: Although I have provided an answer, it is also always useful show example of code or formulas that you have tried, even if it does not work. Then we can then help you  to amend or correct what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full grasp of your issue but have you tried aggregating the conditions in other columns like

Have column G Boolean check if A matches a word in B
Have column H Boolean check if A matches a three letter word in C
Have column I = G OR H
then have your result column based on I?

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to achieve you can do with a nested if statement:

In Cell E1, use this fromula:

```
=IF(A1=B1,D1,IF(A1=C1,D1,""))
```

With the cell still selected, on the bottom right of the cell you will see a small square, click on this small square and drag down to auto-fill all the cells as required.

Answer (score 0):

**Formula:** `=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,B1:C1,0),0)>0,D1,"")`

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What you wrote makes sense, but I guess I forgot to add one crucial detail. The inputs in A are mismatched/unorganized. As in, they have no particular order. But columns B-D are always corresponding. So CRT might be in A2 but b2-d2 will always be Apple APL AP. Does that make sense?